# Custom c++ object pool and alignment

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple dynamically allocated pool of the same object type. For some reason this does not seem to be working well. Do I need to replace malloc with std::aligned_alloc?

```cpp
template<class T>
struct AlwaysGrowingPool
{
  AlwaysGrowingPool() : used(0), capacity(1)
  {
    p_mem = (unsigned char*)std::malloc(capacity * sizeof(T));
  }

  ~AlwaysGrowingPool()
  {
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < used; ++i)
      reinterpret_cast<T*>(&p_mem[i * sizeof(T)])->~T();
    std::free(p_mem);
  }

  template<class... Args>
  T* create(Args&&... args)
  {
    if (used == capacity)
    {
      capacity *= 2;
      unsigned char* p_old_mem = p_mem;
      p_mem = (unsigned char*)std::malloc(capacity * sizeof(T));
      std::memcpy(p_mem, p_old_mem, used * sizeof(T));
      std::free(p_old_mem);
    }
    return new (&p_mem[used++ * sizeof(T)]) T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }

  std::size_t used;
  std::size_t capacity;
  unsigned char* p_mem;
};
```

Comment: `malloc` doesn't guarantee that the allocated memory will be aligned to the requirements of the object being constructed. Try to replace `malloc` with `std::aligned_alloc`(calculate the required alignment and pass it as the first argument) to ensure proper alignment for the objects being stored in the pool. requires C++17 and returns pointer to void - cast to unsigned char* or compatible pointer typer
 
 C++ older than 17 - try aligned_alloc from the <cstdlib> header. different syntax, same function.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "this does not seem to be working well" means? Are there some errors? Performance problems?

Comment: You are aware that this code will only work with trivially copyable types?

Comment: See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable (can be copied using memcpy)

Comment: Sorry for not being more explicit - by "this does not seem to be working well" means I am getting a segfault. Could this be because of memory alignment?

Comment: Possible, not too likely. The more likely hypothesis is that T does not like being moved around. What type is T exactly?

Comment: @teapot418 I've added a static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<T>::value); just in case.

Comment: I think you need to look at the details of the segfault. What was happening at the time? Also your architecture may be relevant, Intel mostly does not care about alignment unless you're doing SSE stuff, RISC archs may be more picky.

Comment: This test for example fails:

  AlwaysGrowingPool<int> pool;
  auto p_1 = pool.create(1);
  auto p_2 = pool.create(2);
  REQUIRE(*p_1 == 1);
  REQUIRE(*p_2 == 2); // *p_2 == 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252504/discussion-between-teapot418-and-mvc).

Comment: @teapot nailed it: this design is flawed since I am returning pointers to memory locations which will become invalid when the pool grows.